# Не открывается ссылка на почте с правильно указанным 'headers' mail()

Tags: php

Пытаюсь отправить пользователю ссылку для входа на сайт, но ссылка полностью не кликабельна.
Может проблема в том, что не указываю глобальный путь, до сайта, но при попытке отправить ссылку с путем, она вообще не отправляется(в спаме ее тоже нет).

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "Ваша ссылка для входа";
$headers = "From: qwer.ru <abc@gmail.com>\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
$massage = '<a href="\login\joinsrc.php \r\n
?login='.$login.'
&email='.$email.'
&telephone=\r\n'.$telephone.'
&password='.$password.'
"\r\n ">'.'Ссылка'.'</a>';
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
mail ($to, $subject, $massage, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Конечно нужно указывать абсолютный путь

```
$message = '<a href="
    http://test.com/login/joinsrc.php 
    ?login='.$login.'
    &email='.$email.'
    &telephone='.$telephone.'
    &password='.$password.'
    ">'.'Ссылка'.'</a>';
mail ($to, $subject, $massage, $headers);
```

Comment: но при попытке вставить абсолютный путь, ссылка вовсе не отправляется

Comment: какой путь Вы вставляете?

Comment: h ttp://test.com\login\joinsrc.php \r\n
    ?login='.$login.'
    &email='.$email.'
    &telephone=\r\n'.$telephone.'
    &password='.$password.'
    "\r\n
только, само собой размеется, на настоящую валидную ссылку

Comment: Слеши должны быть такие `/`. И зачем там `\r\n`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen `\r\n` - требование функции, где строка не должна быть длиннее 70 символов

Comment: @SanyaH PHPMailer поставьте себе и никаких мучений не будет.